# Google Maps API v3, Gray Box, no map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

i want to show multiple point from my database ,I'm only getting a gray box, with controls and Google logo/copyright 
my code as follows,

```
<? 
    $dbname='usedb' ; //Name of the database 
    $dbuser='user' ; //Username for the db 
    $dbpass='pwd' ; //Password for the db 
    $dbserver='localhost' ; //Name of the mysql server 
    $dbcnx=m ysql_connect ( "$dbserver", "$dbuser", "$dbpass"); 
    mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die(mysql_error()); 
?>

  <html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Google Map API V3 with markers</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial;
            }
            #map {
                width: 350px;
                height: 300px;
                border: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?API_KEY"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.google.com/apis/gears/gears_init.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                var icon=new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",new google.maps.Size(32,32),new google.maps.Point(0,0),new google.maps.Point(16,32));
                var center=null;
                var map=null;
                var currentPopup;
                var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                function addMarker(lat,lng,info) {
                    var pt=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                    bounds.extend(pt);
                    var marker=new google.maps.Marker( {
                        position: pt, 
                        icon: icon, 
                        map: map
                    });
                    var popup=new google.maps.InfoWindow( {
                        content: info, 
                        maxWidth: 300
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click",function() {
                        if (currentPopup !=null) {
                            currentPopup.close();
                            currentPopup=null;
                        }
                        popup.open(map,marker);
                        currentPopup=popup;
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(popup,"closeclick",function() {
                        map.panTo(center);
                        currentPopup=null;
                    });
                }

                function initMap() {
                    map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0), 
                    zoom: 14, 
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
                    },
                    navigationControl:true,
                    navigationControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                    }
                });

            <? 
                $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Devices");
                while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                    $name=$row['Hostname'];
                    $lat=$row['Latitude'];
                    $lon=$row['Longitude'];
                    $desc=$row['IPv4'];
                    echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<b>$name</b><br/>$desc');\n");

               }
            ?> 

            center=bounds.getCenter();
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
        </script>
        </head>

        <body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
            <div id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;"></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code ?
Any help will/would be appreciated?

Comment: Is this cut&paste code? `</style>` is missing.

Comment: Check that part which retrieve lat/lng from DB. Without it, just calling `addMarker()` with some values I get correct map with markers.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment noted, please close the `<style>` tag, then change the maps API reference so there is no key.  When I put in your API reference, I got this error:

> Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The
>   provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized
>   for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site. If you are the
>   owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key
>   here:
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

Just put in `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>`

Here is a good, working code snippet.  Use this as a base and change the options to what you want.  The "makeMarker" part is what you want to pull from the database.

```
<html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <title>Google Map API V3 with markers</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 body { font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial; }
 #map { width: 350px; height: 300px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
 </style>

 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.google.com/apis/gears/gears_init.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;">

<script type="text/javascript">

var mapOpts = { mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, zoom: 2, center: new google.maps.LatLng(20, 0) }; 
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOpts); 
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 
var markerArray = []; 

function makeMarker(options) { 
  var pushPin = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map }); 
  pushPin.setOptions(options); 
  google.maps.event.addListener(pushPin, "click", 
  function () { infoWindow.setOptions(options); 
  infoWindow.open(map, pushPin); });
  markerBounds.extend(options.position); 
  markerArray.push(pushPin);
  return pushPin; } google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", 
  function () { infoWindow.close(); }); 

      makeMarker({ title: "Test1", position: new google.maps.LatLng(10, 10), content: "Content1", icon: '' });
      makeMarker({ title: "Test2", position: new google.maps.LatLng(20, 20), content: "Content2", icon: '' });
      makeMarker({ title: "Test3", position: new google.maps.LatLng(30, 30), content: "Content3", icon: '' });

 </script>
 </div>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1 ) google.maps.MarkerImage is deprecated in V3. please use like the following

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      icon: {
          url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png',
          size: new google.maps.Size(10,10)
      }
  });
```

2 ) Please add the following listener to load the Maps API.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

The above listener will load the Map at the page load. **Dont load it in page onload method**.

Comment: **"Dont load it in page onload method"** Why? Both attempts will basically do the same.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, here´s what I found out:

In my case, instead of the map what was displayed within the DIV was just a grey background, as many of you mentioned before. I looked for answers all over the Internet, but couldn´t find anything. I started to try every single element in the code, in order to see where the error was. And... it was nothing but a problem with the  tag!

Let me explain; before I included the map (which I didn´t know was made of several images put together), I had set a previous one within a different function. I ordered such image to be (display:"none") by default, and here´s where the error occurred. I couldn´t see the map because the browser assumed that ALL the images were not to be displayed by default.

It was as silly, but also as simple as that.

I hope this can help you in the future.

**Here´s a screenshot for you all**

[image]